# time data 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00:00 doesn't match format specified

Tags: python, datetime-format, python-datetime, string-to-datetime

I am trying to create a DateTime series with the following date format:
'2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00:00'

```
time_steps = pd.to_datetime(f['forecast_time'][...].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='raise', utc = True)
```

And I am getting the following result:

`time data 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00:00 doesn't match format specified`

When errors= 'coerce' the df returns NaT, when errors = 'ignore' the dtype is Object instead of datetime64.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do you see a difference between the specified datetime format and the format your data is in?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this, as the UTC offset second should be zero (if the `:00` is removed from the format, an error raise):

```py
time_steps = pd.to_datetime(
    '2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00:00', 
    format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z:00', 
    errors='raise', 
    utc = True
)
```

---

Here's a more accurate but dirty way

```py
time_steps = pd.to_datetime(
    '2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00:00'.replace('+', ' +').replace('-', ' -'), 
    format='%Y -%m -%d %H:%M:%S %z', 
    errors='raise', 
    utc = True
)
```